# HtmlHelper does not contain definition for "Action"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use <%= Html.Action("ReadXML") %> and have this error:

'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Action' and no extension method 'Action' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How fix it

This is my assemblies:

```
   <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

  </assemblies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Action` is an extension method contained in the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly. Make sure you have referenced the following namespaces in your web.config:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

The method is declared in the `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace.

Also make sure your project is **ASP.NET MVC 2.0** as [this method has been added in the 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action.aspx) version.

Comment: I have that namespaces in web.config

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC 2.0, the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly version should be 2.0.0.0?

Comment: Yes, i am using ASP.NET MVC 2.0

Comment: I have installed ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2,is this problem

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 2.0 is RTM now. Why installing betas and preview versions when you could use the final release? I am not sure in which of the betas this method has been introduced. What is sure is that it didn't exist in 1.0 RTM and that it exists in 2.0 RTM. You could explore the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly you are using with reflector to verify the non-presence of this extension method.

Comment: tnx Darin, I solved problem (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en#filelist)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is a reference to `System.Web.Mvc` in your project (add it if not already there).

Then make sure the class that is displaying this problem is importing the namespace - you can do this in a couple of ways:

- In the code behind add a `using System.Web.Mvc;` statement at the top.
- You can also import the namespace directly in the `aspx` page if needed, by using this statement: `<%@ import namespace="System.Web.Mvc"%>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the url to an action method inside i.e. a controller you can do:

```
var baseUrl = "http://localhost:12345";
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
var resource = urlHelper.Action("Home", "Index");
var uri = new Uri($"{baseUrl}{resource}");
Console.WriteLine(uri.ToString()); // ==> http://localhost:12345/Home/Index
```